# Vagrant ssh in Windows: ssh_exchange_identification

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

So I'm writing guides to get vagrant working on all different operating systems, and I've saved the worst for last... Windows. I've installed virtualbox, vagrant, and a native ssh command line client so I can execute `ssh servername` successfully. I am also able to run `vagrant up`, and it brings up the machine (I can see in the VBox GUI), but hangs at "waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes...".

Trying to run `vagrant ssh` from the command prompt yields an error, sure enough.

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I'm fairly new to networking, and I have no idea what is going wrong here. Is it an issue with the private key? (I have the paths for the private key configured properly), or is it a Windows network issue? I haven't been able to find the answer online yet and would appreciate some help. Thanks! A fix would be amazing.

Comment: ok, I fixed the issue and got it working by manually booting the system and running fsck then rebooting twice. It seems to be an error with the system clock on the VM. Does anyone know why on earth this would be happenening?

Comment: System clocks in VMs tend to go off because the VM does not get all CPU cycles the host has available - for that reason VirtualBox has a mechanism to sync the clock using guest additions if it's more than 10 minutes off the host's.

Answer (score 1):

You can try rebooting the machine with

```
vagrant reload (CTRL + C if it takes too long)
```

And then try

```
vagrant up
```

Now you should be able to ssh back in with

```
vagrant ssh
```